# How to insert a commentary line in a PL/SQL file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, insertion

Here's my problem, I want to had in PL/SQL code commentary with SVN's Keywords.
The problem is that in production the commentaries above the `CREATE OR REPLACE` is ereased when compiling.

Then to do this I have to add the **commentary lines** just after the line `CREATE OR REPLACE [name] [AS/IS]`.
My problem is that I have absolutely no idea to process with a **Shell script**.
I think I would use awk but I'm not a master of this tool at all :S

For exemple I got a file like this:

```
-- Comments here will be deleted when compiling
-- That's why i must had my comment after the CREATE OR REPLACE
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_file
IS
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   --  Version     Date          Person    Comments
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   CODE
   .
   .
   .
```

And I want a file like that:

```
-- Comments here will be deleted when compiling
-- That's why i must had my comment after the CREATE OR REPLACE
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_file
IS
   -- REVISION $Revision$
   -- ID $Id$
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   --  Version     Date          Person    Comments
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   CODE
   .
   .
   .
```

Of course I could write it one by one in each file. But there's a lot of files that's why I'm looking for a way to do this really faster.

Thanks,

Ežekiel.

Comment: This is way better. Is the format always `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` + new line + `IS`?

Comment: The format can be like this :
`CREATE OR REPLACE ...` [new line] `IS` or
`CREATE OR REPLACE ...` [new line] `AS` or 
`CREATE OR REPLACE ... IS` [new line] or 
`CREATE OR REPLACE ... AS` [new line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/CREATE OR REPLACE/{n=NR} 
           /^IS/ && NR==n+1{print; 
                            print "   -- REVISION ...";
                            print "   -- ID ...";
                            next
                           } 1' sql
```

mark the first pattern "CREATE..." and if the next line starts with "IS" insert the two comment lines.

UPDATE: now looks for AS or IS, not just at the next line but between the same line and 3 following lines

```
$ awk        '/CREATE OR REPLACE/{n=NR} 
  /\yIS|AS\y/ && n<=NR && NR<=n+3{
             print; 
             print "  -- REVISION ...\n  -- ID ...";
             next} 1' sql
```

set the variable n with the line number when first pattern matches, searches for the second pattern within 3 line neighborhood and inserts the lines after a match.

Comment: Nice! Note [there are some other possibilities of format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400005/how-to-insert-a-commentary-line-in-a-pl-sql-file#comment56542102_34400005).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've added `/^(IS|AS)/` to handle the both forms `[new line] + AS or IS` but when it's on the same line I'm blocked, what does `{n=NR}` means ? I have the idea to say a thing like `/CREATE OR REPLACE/{n= NR}/^IS/ || /CREATE OR REPLACE/{n=NR}/(IS|AS)`
But it doesn't works because I don't know how to write it correctly in awk :(

Comment: It's ok guy !! Thanks you very much I finally understood HOW awk is working ! I understood your NR==n+1 etc to see if it's the just next line etc ! Awk is a very cool tool when you know how to use it !

Answer (score 0):

A `gawk` solution to handle the `AS` `IS` permutations:

```
gawk '/^--/ && f < 2 {comment[++c]=$0;next}
    /CREATE OR REPLACE/{++f;create=$0}
    /\y(IS|AS)\y/{
              print create
              if ($0!=create) {
                print $0
              }
              ++f
              for (j=1;j<=c;j++){
                print comment[j]
              }
              next
    }
    f==2 {print} ' source.sql
```

**Results**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_file
IS
-- Comments here will be deleted when compiling
-- That's why i must had my comment after the CREATE OR REPLACE
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   --  Version     Date          Person    Comments
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   CODE
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer guy, I keep your answer in my mind but actually I just have the `awk` and I can't install `gawk` for a system reason.
I don't really understand the "goal" of your solution, how does it handle the `AS|IS` permutation form ? It's not clear in my mind when I see your example ^^